# How to provide remote control feature on tizen TV

Tags: content-management-system, tizen-web-app, vnc-server

we have our own cms system and need to add feature to access tizen device remotely.
I have check various docs and pdf, but enable to get exact approach used behind.
Some where it was mentioned that we need to install vnc server on the tizen tv, which will help us to connect tizen tv remotly. but how can we install vnc server on tizen tv.

Comment: Would you add more detailed information? Need to control a normal TV, or, a Signage, or, several devices, or, B2B TVs (e.g. Hotel TVs)?

Comment: It is B2B and Signage

Comment: For signage, how about to use this solution? https://www.magicinfoservices.com/magicinfo-remote-management-solution/

Comment: Yes I tried, but it is paid. I need to create it manually

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what platform you are using. I am familiar with Samsung's QM models and will offer what I know about those. I presume what I say here generalises to all models supporting SSSP 5+.

I can think of two alternatives to the MagicInfo RM Server.

1. Reverse engineer the MagicInfo RM protocol and create your own server. I would take a close look at your partnership agreement before trying that.
2. Create your own SSSP application. For this to help you it has to always be running. The way you do that is with URL Launcher. I am not sure if it is possible for your application to *not* take over the screen. There are also some limitations to what system calls an SSSP application can make.

Up to you to figure out what meets your requirements.

From a fiscal perspective, you should weigh what Samsung's RM Server will cost you in licensing fees versus what it will cost you to develop and maintain a custom solution. Keep in mind, SSSP is a moving target.

You mentioned VNC. When you make an SSSP application you can also make a Nodejs application along with it. Ask Samsung and they will tell you about it. I am sure there are npm packages for VNC that can help you. Maybe there is a VNC web client and you do not need to bother with Nodejs at all. There is NaCl too.

Comment: Hi @erisco, Thanks for the reply.
I have tried to do reverse engineering on magicInfo RM Protocol. But haven't got any success.
From There itself I got to know that we can achieve this using VNC.
I want to create a custom solution for remote server. To achieve flexibility.

Comment: I vaguely recall some remote desktop support but I'll have to dig up my notes. Could take me a few days.

Comment: yeah sure. Thank you

Comment: RDP support can be enabled through the factory menu `Control → LFD Options → RDP Support` and then accessed by changing the source to `Remote Workspace`.

Comment: Sorry, Not got your point. Can please provide the proper steps to connect tizen tv from remote?